# Python Flask: the link in the returned text is not working

Tags: python, flask

I have built an app where the app is returning a bunch of `strings`. Some of the string is hyperlinked and thus clickable.

Below is the code snippet where the string is returned in `@app.route('/response/', methods = ['POST']` process

```
def conv(text):
    new_s = re.sub('[\w\.-]+@[\w\.-]+\.\w+', lambda x:f'<a href=" {x.group()}">{x.group()}</a>', text)
    url_str = 'abc.xys.com'
    url_rep = 'abc.xys.com:8080'
    new_s = new_s.replace(url_str,f'<a href "{url_rep}">{url_str}</a>')
    return new_s


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/response/',methods = ['GET','POST'])
def response(): 
     #...codes.....# 
     return conv(string) # string is the actual string which is being returned

if __name__ == "__main__":
print("**Starting Server...")

#load_model()

app.run(port=5002, debug=True)
```

The above code works fine. Except the links which, upon clicking, are being redirected to the `localhost:5002` itself. Rather I want to redirect that link to `abc.xys.com:8080`. For email related link it shows the following error:

```
URL Not found
```

Is there any changes need to be done at `app.run()`? Or any other stuffs I am missing out?

Comment: Have you looked at the returned string in a browser's developer tools to see what the pseudo-HTML looks like and ensure the link is well formed and contains what you expect?

Comment: the link is well formed and HTML is ok.

Comment: What happens if you copy the link from the page source and paste it into the URL bar of your browser? Does it work, or still redirect?

Comment: Yes it does work. Infact I had created a simple HTML file with the link pasted in `<body>` part. It did work.

Comment: Any thought on this? Or this should be handled at Front End?